# Is it safe to use conditional operators with volatile primitives in multithreaded applications

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, volatile, conditional-operator

In the `below code listings`, are Statement 1 and Statement 2 thread safe or not?  They are using the `VolatileIntWrapper`.

If they not thread safe, which statements need to be wrapped in synchronized block?

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        VolatileIntWrapper volatileIntWrapper = new VolatileIntWrapper() ;

        for(int i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; ++i){
            new ModifyWrapperIntValue(volatileIntWrapper).start() ; 
        }
    }
}

class VolatileIntWrapper{
    public volatile int value = 0 ;
}

class ModifyWrapperIntValue extends Thread{

    private VolatileIntWrapper wrapper ;
    private int counter = 0 ;

    public ModifyWrapperIntValue(VolatileIntWrapper viw) {
        this.wrapper = viw ;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        //randomly increments or decrements VolatileIntWrapper primitive int value

        //we can use below statement also, if value in VolatileIntWrapper is private
        // wrapper.getValue() instead of wrapper.value
        //but, as per my understanding, it will add more complexity to logic(might be requires additional synchronized statements),
        //so, for simplicity, we declared it public


        //Statement 1
        while(wrapper.value > -1500 && wrapper.value < 1500){
            ++counter ;
            int randomValue = (int) (Math.random() * 2) ;

            //Statement 2
            wrapper.value += (randomValue == 0) ?   1       :       -1 ;
        }

        System.out.println("Executed " + counter + " times...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`volatile` keyword](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml) provides a memory barrier for both reading and writing a field.  That means that multiple threads can access the field and be guaranteed to read the most current value and their writes are guaranteed to be seen by other threads.

What `volatile` does *not* do is provide any guarantees around the order of operations -- especially when you have multiple read and write statements.  In your code you are accessing the `volatile int` a couple of places in your loop:

```
    while(wrapper.value > -1500 && wrapper.value < 1500){
        ...
        wrapper.value += (randomValue == 0) ?   1       :       -1 ;
    }
```

There are no guarantees as to the order of operations here.  Immediately after thread A tests the `value > -1500`, another thread might change it *before* thread A can test `value < 1500`.  Or thread A might do both tests, then thread B might do both tests, then thread A would assign the value, and then thread B would assign the value.  That is the nature of [multithreading race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Computing).

The `while` loop is the section of code that I suspect would be considered have a bug unless you synchronize around it.  You should do something like the following.  Once you are synchronizing that section, the `synchronized` keyword provides the memory barrier itself and so the `volatile` keyword is unnecessary.

```
   synchronized (wrapper) {
       while (...) {
         ...
       }
   }
```

Comment: it shows the definition:  `class VolatileIntWrapper{
    public volatile int value = 0 ;
}`

Comment: Thanks @Mike.  Overlooked that.

Answer (score 2):

It is safe to use a volatile field once and only once. (A read and a write counts as twice)

You are using the field a total of four times so you have three places for a race condition.

The problem with this example is it is faster and simpler to be performed single threaded, so anything you do with it in a multi-threaded way will appear unnatural and inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

The question needs the following interpretation:

The thread you are using is safe and you are reading your primitive value as it is intended.

there is a specific term to use synchronize blocks on the primitive field, but you need to do the following:

- Use getter and setters of your field.
- Put synchronize in the both accessors and voila.

Answer (score 0):

`Java In Concurrencty` says the following criteria need to be met touse volatile variables:

> ```
> 1.  Writes to the variable do not depend on its current value, or you can ensure that only a single thread ever updates the value;
>
> 2.  The variable does not participate in invariants with other state variables; and
>
> 3.  Locking is not required for any other reason while the variable is being accessed.
> ```